# Split string into substring over '\n' in Python

Tags: python, string, split, newline

I am reading string extracts of a long DNA data file in Python. Some string extracts run over a new line in the .txt file. Python prints these string extracts with the `'\n'` character in the string. 
[image: Here's a pic]

My problem is that I don't know how to detect substrings that fall on either side of the newline character `'\n'`.

IE: in the code below, `'gca'` is found, but `'taa'` is not. What's the proper solution to this?

```
l = 'gcaacacgactta\naccaagctgt'

for i in range(0, len(l), 3):

    if l[i:i+3] == 'taa':
        print(l[i:i+3])

    elif l[i:i+3] == 'gca':
        print((l[i:i+3]))

>>>gca
```

EDIT: I intended to search for `'aac'` and not `'taa'`. Regardless, `.replace()` works. Thanks guys!

Comment: remove all `\n`? l = l.replace("\n", "")

Comment: If it's printing `\n` then there must be `\\n` in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating every 3 characters, in this case: `gca` `aca` `cga` `ctt` `aac` `caa` `gct` `gt`. You cannot find `taa` because it is not in one of the above elements. To have both `gca` and `taa` you can do so:

```
l = 'gcaacacgactta\naccaagctgt'
l = l.replace("\n","")

for i in range(len(l)):

    if l[i:i+3] == 'taa':
        print(l[i:i+3])

    elif l[i:i+3] == 'gca':
        print((l[i:i+3]))
```

Output:

```
gca
taa
```

### Edit

If you want `gca` and `aac`, and all your sequence is in triple, just `replace` is enough and this is will be output:

```
gca
aac
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Replace the '\n' to ""

2) Change `range(0, len(l), 3)` to `range(len(l)-3)`,

```
l = 'gcaacacgactta\naccaagctgt'

l=l.replace("\n","")

for i in range(len(l)-3):

    if l[i:i+3] == 'aac':
        print(l[i:i+3])

    elif l[i:i+3] == 'gca':
        print((l[i:i+3]))
```

Comment: i voted down because Joe answer is very similar. Thanks

Comment: @JON,Can you please check the answer timeline?

Comment: Correct, i have seen, Thanks

Comment: I tried to change it, But apps could not allow, i can do it only when answer has some difference from previous. From next time i will change that too, thanks

Answer (score -1):

I hope this may help

```
l = 'gcaacacgactta\nataaccaagctgt'
l=l.replace("\n","")
taa_index=l.find('taa')
while(True):
    print(l[taa_index:taa_index+3])
    p=(l[taa_index+3:]).find('taa')
    if p!=-1:
        taa_index = p+taa_index+3
    else:
        break
```

Similarly you can do for 'gca'. Now this would work for multiple 'taa'

Comment: what if 'taa' occurs twice in the string?